# SPD Workflow 2013. People or group column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a list with a column called Selected Approvers or type Person or group. 
ex:
Person 1,Person 2 , Person 3

When I assign a Workflow variable to this the variable is being assigned as
Person 2, Person 1, Person 3.
 I am wondering what would cause this.

I then logged the user Ids and they are all somehow being read in ascending order by WF
5;21;25;
Person 2, Person 1, Person 3.

instead of 
21;5;25
Person 1,Person 2,Person 3

If I read the variable as plain string it dumps out ids in the order expected.
results:[5,24,1,29]

So If i read the variable as Displaynames, loginnames,email it sorts it by the userids. I want to maintain the order these were entered.
Please let me know if you have any insights
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to get the SelectedApprovers with ids , assign it to a string , then do string operations and loop each id to get the user and assign the user the task. This solved my issue although not as clean as I would have liked. 
Let me know if anyone else has come across this issue.
thanks